# Extract value from Object.entries

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return just the key value if there is a match.

```
const codes = {
  key1: 'dafault',
  key2: 'dog112',
  key3: 'catStick',
};

const match = 'dog'

const result = Object.entries(codes).filter(([, v]) => {
    console.log('v = ', v);
    return v.includes(match);
});

console.log('result = ', result);
// Array(2) ["key2", "dog112"]
```

I just need to return the key value. How can I extract the key value or is there a simpler way to just return the key if there is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the key, you should `.find` over the `Object.keys`:

```js
const codes = {
  key1: 'dafault',
  key2: 'dog112',
  key3: 'catStick',
};

const match = 'dog'

const result = Object.keys(codes).find(
  key => codes[key].includes(match)
);

console.log('result = ', result);
```

The `result` will be `undefined` if nothing is found.

Comment: Ah find I totally forgot about that. than you.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do:

```js
Object.values(codes).some((item, i) => {
  const match = item.contains('dog')
  if (match) {
    console.log(Object.keys(codes)[i])
  }
  return match
})
```

This will stop the loop once found. Most performant.

This will print to the console `key2`